# Check if small set is part of big set in CPLEX OPL

Tags: cplex, opl

```
execute{ 
   for(t in bigset){ 
      if((t inter smallset) == t){
```

gives an error on the if line: Scripting parser error: missing ')'.

Answer (score 0):

```
{int} s={1,2};

{int} bigS={1,2,3};

sorted {int} interset=s inter bigS;
sorted {int} s2={i | i in s};

int v0=and(i in s)(i in bigS);
int v1=and(j in 0..card(s2)-1) item(interset,j)==item(s2,j);
int v2=1;

execute
{
  writeln(v1);
  
  for(var t in s){ 
      if (!bigS.contains(t)) { v2=0; }
    }      
  writeln(v2);    
  
  writeln(Opl.operatorINTER(s,bigS));
}
```

gives

```
1
1
1
 {1 2}
```